# Apache: How to Block "curl --insecure" in a ssl virtual host

Tags: apache, web-services, security, curl, ssl-certificate

I did create a ssl virtualhost in apache with a self-signed certificate.

In my opinion the configuration is correct however it is possible to access this url using "curl --insecure".

Searching at google, reading several tutorials and trying several configurations (diretives SSLVerifyClient|SSLVerifyDepth|AuthType|AuthBasicProvider|AuthUserFile|Require valid-user) I did not have any success in block this url using "curl --insecure"

I have been thinking in testing mod_security but I don't know if is the right way.

Could you give me some advice?

Thanks
Hudson

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may need to refine the understanding of sleep.  You can't force clients to verify your SSL certificate.  Besides, if you're using a self signed cert, it would never verify for anyone who didn't add the cert to their ca library.

You could block curl by rejecting requests based on their User Agent string.  But that's just a header, and can be set by the client to anything ( such as a "valid" browser URL).  If you really want to control clients, one way would be to use *client certificates*, which is the analog of the server certificate you set up, but on the client side.   In that case, in addition to the client (ostensibly) verifying the server's cert, the server would verify the client's cert, providing a very strong and reliable mechanism to verify client access.  Unfortunately, due the the difficulty of generating keys and cert signing requests, and signing certs for clients, client http certificates are not common.  But they're very secure, and a good choice if you control both sides.

A middle ground would be to add an authentication layer into your app to control who can access it (you'd then refuse unauthenticated requests altogether)

In short, though, none of these things block curl.  They block clients who cannot authenticate. I would recommend you not focus on the remote browser/client in use ( that's at the discretion of your http client).  instead, focus on providing the security authentication you require.  IMHO, trying to block client user-agents is a fool's errand.  It's security by obscurity.  Anyone can set any user-agent.

Comment: Hi Dan:
Yes, I am a little confused. :)
The self-signed certificate is just for testing.
My goal is to avoid the use of tools like curl to access a SSL domain.
Using the "insecure" option the client can get the page content because curl does not check the SSL certificate. 
I did think about use SSLRequire or SetEnvIf to test page headers but i don't know if this will work because each tool can have a different header.

Comment: I tried to add some color to my answer to help  address what you've included

Comment: Hi Dan. Sorry for the delay. Your answer was enlightening!
Reading other answers and studying some tutorials about firewalls i did realize that curl only shows the insecure connections without change the SSL connection. Would be better to install the certificate in both sides(client and server) but perhaps adding a authentication layer in the application would be more pratical because the programmer will have more autonomy.
Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Glad it could help.  Yeah, most sites don't use client certificates.